# How to Close external Excel opened from local vlookup reference on vba

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to close another Excel workbook opened from my active excel when calling vlookup which references that other Excel.  The closest I could get is to close the workbook but Excel remains open.  I did not want to be radical and close all Excel instances as it would close other workbooks not involved in the process. The Main Sub called InsertLookup calls other Subs.  I can close the active excel but the one opened by vlookup (OtherExcel.Xlsx) remains open.  I don't want to have any of the two excel files involved in the process to remain open.

```
Option Explicit


Public RemoteRowCount As Long
Public LocalRowCount As Long

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
    If Err Then
        Is_WorkBook_Open = False
    Else
        Is_WorkBook_Open = True
    End If
End Function


Sub GetRemoteRowCount()
    Dim LastRowRemote As Long

    Dim WkBks As Workbook
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\local\OtherExcel.Xlsx"


    If Is_WorkBook_Open("OtherExcel.Xlsx") Then
        Set WkBks = Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx")
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test\OtherExcel.Xlsx"
    End If
    Set WShts = WkBks.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
    LastRowRemote = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RemoteRowCount = LastRowRemote
End Sub


Sub GetLocalRowCount()
    Dim LastRowLocal As Long
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WShts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet")
    LastRowLocal = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LocalRowCount = LastRowLocal
    'MsgBox (LocalRowCount)
End Sub


Sub InsertLookup()
    Call GetRemoteRowCount
    Call GetLocalRowCount

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, LastValue As String, i As Integer    

    For i = 3 To LocalRowCount
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "G").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "G").Value) = False Then
            LastValue = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, "N").Offset(, -7).Value & ",[OtherExcel.XLSX]FirstSheet!R13C1:R" & RemoteRowCount & "C12,10,0)"
            Cells(i, "N").Formula = LastValue
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Call DeleteAllSubs
    Call CloseExcel
End Sub


Sub DeleteAllSubs()
    Dim otmp As Object

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each otmp In .VBComponents
            If otmp.Type=100 Then
                otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close
            Else: .VBComponents.Remove otmp
            End If
        Next otmp
    End With
End Sub


Option Explicit

Public RemoteRowCount As Long
Public LocalRowCount As Long

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
    If Err Then
        Is_WorkBook_Open = False
    Else
        Is_WorkBook_Open = True
    End If
End Function


Sub GetRemoteRowCount()
    Dim LastRowRemote As Long

    Dim WkBks As Workbook
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\local\OtherExcel.Xlsx"


    If Is_WorkBook_Open("OtherExcel.Xlsx") Then
        Set WkBks = Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx")
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test\OtherExcel.Xlsx"
    End If
    Set WShts = WkBks.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
    LastRowRemote = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RemoteRowCount = LastRowRemote
End Sub


Sub GetLocalRowCount()
    Dim LastRowLocal As Long
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WShts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet")
    LastRowLocal = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LocalRowCount = LastRowLocal
    'MsgBox (LocalRowCount)
End Sub


Sub InsertLookup()
    Call GetRemoteRowCount
    Call GetLocalRowCount


    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, LastValue As String, i As Integer    

    For i = 3 To LocalRowCount
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "G").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "G").Value) = False Then
            LastValue = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, "N").Offset(, -7).Value & ",[OtherExcel.XLSX]FirstSheet!R13C1:R" & RemoteRowCount & "C12,10,0)"
            Cells(i, "N").Formula = LastValue
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Call DeleteAllSubs
    Call CloseExcel
End Sub


Sub DeleteAllSubs()
    Dim otmp As Object

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each otmp In .VBComponents
            If otmp.Type=100 Then
                otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close
            Else: .VBComponents.Remove otmp
            End If
        Next otmp
    End With
End Sub


Option Explicit

Public RemoteRowCount As Long
Public LocalRowCount As Long

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
    If Err Then
        Is_WorkBook_Open = False
    Else
        Is_WorkBook_Open = True
    End If
End Function


Sub GetRemoteRowCount()
    Dim LastRowRemote As Long

    Dim WkBks As Workbook
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\local\OtherExcel.Xlsx"


    If Is_WorkBook_Open("OtherExcel.Xlsx") Then
        Set WkBks = Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx")
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test\OtherExcel.Xlsx"
    End If
    Set WShts = WkBks.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
    LastRowRemote = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RemoteRowCount = LastRowRemote
End Sub
Sub GetLocalRowCount()
    Dim LastRowLocal As Long
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WShts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet")
    LastRowLocal = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LocalRowCount = LastRowLocal
    'MsgBox (LocalRowCount)
End Sub


Sub InsertLookup()
    Call GetRemoteRowCount
    Call GetLocalRowCount


    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, LastValue As String, i As Integer    

    For i = 3 To LocalRowCount
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "G").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "G").Value) = False Then
            LastValue = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, "N").Offset(, -7).Value & ",[OtherExcel.XLSX]FirstSheet!R13C1:R" & RemoteRowCount & "C12,10,0)"
            Cells(i, "N").Formula = LastValue
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Call DeleteAllSubs
    Call CloseExcel
End Sub


Sub DeleteAllSubs()
    Dim otmp As Object

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each otmp In .VBComponents
            If otmp.Type=100 Then
                otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close
            Else: .VBComponents.Remove otmp
            End If
        Next otmp
    End With
End Sub


Option Explicit

Public RemoteRowCount As Long
Public LocalRowCount As Long

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
    If Err Then
        Is_WorkBook_Open = False
    Else
        Is_WorkBook_Open = True
    End If
End Function


Sub GetRemoteRowCount()
    Dim LastRowRemote As Long

    Dim WkBks As Workbook
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\local\OtherExcel.Xlsx"


    If Is_WorkBook_Open("OtherExcel.Xlsx") Then
        Set WkBks = Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx")
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test\OtherExcel.Xlsx"
    End If
    Set WShts = WkBks.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
    LastRowRemote = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RemoteRowCount = LastRowRemote
End Sub


Sub GetLocalRowCount()
    Dim LastRowLocal As Long
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WShts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet")
    LastRowLocal = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LocalRowCount = LastRowLocal
    'MsgBox (LocalRowCount)
End Sub


Sub InsertLookup()
    Call GetRemoteRowCount
    Call GetLocalRowCount


    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, LastValue As String, i As Integer    

    For i = 3 To LocalRowCount
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "G").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "G").Value) = False Then
            LastValue = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, "N").Offset(, -7).Value & ",[OtherExcel.XLSX]FirstSheet!R13C1:R" & RemoteRowCount & "C12,10,0)"
            Cells(i, "N").Formula = LastValue
        End If
    Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Call DeleteAllSubs
Call CloseExcel
End Sub


Sub DeleteAllSubs()
    Dim otmp As Object

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each otmp In .VBComponents
            If otmp.Type=100 Then
                otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close
            Else: .VBComponents.Remove otmp
            End If
        Next otmp
    End With
End Sub
Option Explicit



Public RemoteRowCount As Long
Public LocalRowCount As Long

Function Is_WorkBook_Open(ByVal strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
    If Err Then
        Is_WorkBook_Open = False
    Else
        Is_WorkBook_Open = True
    End If
End Function


Sub GetRemoteRowCount()
    Dim LastRowRemote As Long

    Dim WkBks As Workbook
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\local\OtherExcel.Xlsx"


    If Is_WorkBook_Open("OtherExcel.Xlsx") Then
        Set WkBks = Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx")
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\test\OtherExcel.Xlsx"
    End If
    Set WShts = WkBks.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
    LastRowRemote = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RemoteRowCount = LastRowRemote
End Sub


Sub GetLocalRowCount()
    Dim LastRowLocal As Long
    Dim WShts As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set WShts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherSheet")
    LastRowLocal = WShts.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LocalRowCount = LastRowLocal
    'MsgBox (LocalRowCount)
End Sub

Sub InsertLookup()
    Call GetRemoteRowCount
    Call GetLocalRowCount


    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, LastValue As String, i As Integer    

    For i = 3 To LocalRowCount
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "G").Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, "G").Value) = False Then
            LastValue = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(i, "N").Offset(, -7).Value & ",[OtherExcel.XLSX]FirstSheet!R13C1:R" & RemoteRowCount & "C12,10,0)"
            Cells(i, "N").Formula = LastValue
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Call DeleteAllSubs
    Call CloseExcel
End Sub


Sub DeleteAllSubs()
    Dim otmp As Object

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each otmp In .VBComponents
            If otmp.Type=100 Then
                otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close
            Else: .VBComponents.Remove otmp
            End If
        Next otmp
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not necessary to post all your code... Try selecting only of the relevant part which does something different then you like. And clearly explain which are your expectations and how the code does not fulfill them. What deleting lines in `VBProject.Code` module has in common with the question as you presented it? Basically, it is so simple to close any open workbook... I do not have enough patience to look for such a sequence in such a bushy code. Sorry...

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to close the workbook from a sub that has not set the workbook. Would `Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx").close` work?

Comment: @FaneDuru  the part that is trying to do everything is Sub InsertLookup

Comment: Then, use `Workbooks("OtherExcel.XLSX").Close False`. `False` if you do not want it to be saved...  But, I can see there `ActiveWorkbook.Close` followed by some rows deletion in the `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject`. Which this `ActiveWorkbook` would you like to be? The one which you just closed before, or another one?

Comment: @DavesExcel OtherExcel is opened when I call the sub that returns row count. Remains open when I call the InsertLookup sub. And I am trying to close both excel files.  Workbooks("OtherExcel.Xlsx").close does not work.

Comment: @FaneDuru  What I am trying to call as active is the one that is calling vlookup on OtherExcel.xlsx.  I wanted to have rowcount for both OtherExcel.xlsx and current file as I needed to insert vlookup on all rows of current file but I found that I had to activate current file to be able to insert lookup, otherwise insertion would not work. My intention is to close OtherExcel.xlsx and the current file. Workbooks("OtherExcel.XLSX").Close False did not work. I am calling that before calling Call RemoveAll

Comment: But, do you have such a workbook named "OtherExcel.XLSX", or this is only a generic name? Now, I must live my office...

Comment: FaneDuru OtherExcel.XLSX is an alias of the actual name.

Comment: And that 'alias' exists, but it does not want to close... This is what you want to transmit?

Comment: Hello.  I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167475/how-to-close-blank-excel-workbook-along-with-macro-workbook.  I added this in the end of Sub FillVLookupOnCells():                                                                                                    ActiveWorkbook.Save
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Call RemoveAll
Excel.Parent.Quit
Application.Quit
End Sub